# How to Remove caption buttons overlay artifact in .NET MAUI targeting windows 11?

Tags: .net, maui

I get a visual artifact in caption button area when setting `window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar` to `true`.

[image]

I used the following code in MauiProgram.cs class `CreateMauiApp()` method.

```cs
builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
{
#if WINDOWS
    events.AddWindows(windowsLifecycleBuilder =>
    {
        windowsLifecycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
        {
            window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;
            window.SystemBackdrop = new DesktopAcrylicBackdrop();
        });
    });
#endif
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to [[WinUI 3] Windows App Title Bar Buttons Have Button Shadows in .NET8 after project upgrade from .NET7 #18773](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18773). And the issue is that in app title bar where the minimize, maximize, and close buttons have a shadow in **WinUI3**. You can follow up it.

As an alternative workaround, you can refer to [Title bar still not behaving correctly](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7123). Add below code in `App.xaml\Windows\Platforms`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MauiAppTitleBarContainerTemplate">
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      <ContentControl
      Grid.Column="4"
      IsTabStop="False"
      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
      x:Name="AppTitleBarContentControl">
      </ContentControl>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```